# "Upload" a file into buffer and stop rails saving any uploads in a tmp dir

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, buffer

I am thinking how to upload a file without saving it neither in a tmp dir nor everywhere else. I just need the raw data (bites) so I can use it in buffer and handle it as raw data.

The problem is that rails automatically saves files in a temp dir when they are uploaded. I would like to stop this behaviour. When is the file removed from the temp dir?

The params looks like this

`{"a_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff01d261aa0 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/7n/__mg6lwj1nx17qzlx9xrtvnm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131228-5260-mpj993>, @original_filename="blog-head.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test[a_file]\"; filename=\"blog-head.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save Test", "controller"=>"test", "action"=>"create"}`

As you can see, the file is saved in `/var/folders/7n/__mg6lwj1nx17qzlx9xrtvnm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131228-5260-mpj993`. The file is really physically there. I would like to stop this for whole application. For example as a user if I modify any form and I add there the file input, I can physically save any file in file system. I am pretty sure my unix system handles it somehow so it's safe and the file can not corrupt anything. I would sleep better if rails doesn't do that 'automagically'. I would like to handle it on my own :)

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that when I place a debugger into the controller, it seems rails save it automatically into a temp dir. I will update the question

Comment: Isn't tempfile generated by the server to avoid memory exceeding?

Comment: Indeed it's. ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile documentation says that the file is saved there only for the request, then the file is thrown away. I am pretty sure rails do this automatically to prevent from DDOS attacks as an attacker could send a file bigger than my memory. I can handle size limit of an upload on my http server so maybe it would be good to have an option to disable this behaviour. (It seems this configuration is not implemented). Thanks for the discussion anyway. It helped

Comment: Yeah, by server I meant nginx/webrick/whatever is handling your requests. I don't think Rails handles storing tempfile. Check out this post: https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw